# Test where clause in sqlalchemy select object

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write some functions to build sqlalchemy select statements. For instance:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

t_test = sa.Table(
    'test', metadata,
    sa.Column('col_1', sa.Text),
    sa.Column('col_2', sa.Float)
)

def create_test_select():
    sa_select = sa.select([t_test.c.col_1, t_test.c.col_2])
    return sa_select

def add_test_col1_where_clause(sa_select, x ):
    sa_select = sa_select.where(t_test.c.col_1 == x)
    return sa_select
```

I would like to test these functions.

To test `create_test_select` I would write something like

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):    
    def test(self):
         self.assertIn('col1', create_test_select().columns)
         self.assertIn('col2', create_test_select().columns)
```

How can I test that the function `add_test_col1_where_clause`? I would like to know that it adds the correct where clause to the select. My initial thought was to examine the where clause in sqlachemy select object but I haven't been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLAlchemy doesn't directly expose the 'where' clause part of a select; not all SELECT statements have one, after all. In addition, the clause can become rather complex. Personally, I'd only test the expressions in an integration test, and only to make sure the correct data is returned.

SQLAlchemy does give you tools to visit the object tree, albeit somewhat underdocumented. You could use this to extract any comparisons from the tree, so `<left> <op> <right>` expressions where `left` and `right` are *columns elements*:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import visitors, ColumnElement

def comparison_visitor(expr, callback):
    """Finds all binary operators, and calls callback(op, left, right)"""
    def visit_binary(op):
        callback(op, op.left, op.right)
    # visit each expr element, but for select clauses, ignore the column collection
    visitors.traverse(expr, {'column_collections': False}, {'binary': visit_binary})
```

`visitors.traverse()` traverses any SQLAlchemy expression (by repeatedly calling the [`ColumnClause.get_children()` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement.get_children) of the objects, passing in the mapping given as the second argument to `traverse()`), and calls the function that matches the `__visit_name__` attribute of each object. `BinaryClause` objects have `binary` as the visit name.

You can then use this to test if specific conditions are present:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import operators
from sqlalchemy.sql.expressions import BindParameter
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column

def test_where(self):
    where = add_test_col1_where_clause(create_test_select(), 'foo bar')

    def test_comparison(op, left, right):
        self.assertIs(op.operator, operators.eq)    # == test

        self.assertIsInstance(left, Column)         # between the col_1 column
        self.assertEq(left.name, 'col_1')

        self.assertIsInstance(right, BindParameter) # and a parameter
        self.assertEq(right.value, 'foo bar')       # with value 'foo bar'

    comparison_visitor(where, test_comparison)
```